# How to tell rsyslog to use Unix domain sockets to write syslog messages to a Postgresql database?

Tags: rsyslog, postgresql

I created a database as explained here:

https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/blob/master/plugins/ompgsql/createDB.sql

I created a "root" user in the database and granted insert permissions:

```sql
Syslog=# create user "root";
Syslog=# grant insert on table SystemEvents to "root";
Syslog=# grant insert on table SystemEventsProperties to "root";
```

The connections works fine:

```bash
# psql Syslog -c '\conninfo'
You are connected to database "Syslog" as user "root" via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5432".
```

Then I tried several different ways to specify the host in the "rsyslog.conf":

```
*.* action(type="ompgsql" server="" db="Syslog" uid="root" pwd="")
*.* action(type="ompgsql" server="/run/postgresql" db="Syslog" uid="root" pwd="")
*.* action(type="ompgsql" server="/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" db="Syslog" uid="root" pwd="")
```

Nothing works. I get always the error:

> db error (1): no connection to the server   [v8.2102.0]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `server` action parameter should be a hostname or ip address, so try `server="localhost"` in
the first action. See the [config
page](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/ompgsql.html)
examples.

You can also try replacing all the parameters by a `conninfo` which uses a standard [PostgreSQL URI](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) format, for example:

```
action(type="ompgsql" conninfo="postgresql://root:@localhost/Syslog")
```

You shouldn't need to specify the Unix domain socket, but the URI
documentation shows how you can do so, for example:

```
postgresql://root/Syslog?host=/var/run/postgresql
```

Comment: `conninfo` is not available in Debian 11. Requires at least Debian 12.

Comment: [Works fine with Rsyslog 8.2302.](https://gist.github.com/ceving/4eae4437d793ae4752b8582253872067)